# How to groupby json value like python in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm new in java but I have some knowledge in python,
I need to transform json value like this:

```
{'ID':'id1','ref':'ref1','categ':'CATEG_A','pagenb':1},
{'ID':'id2','ref':'ref1','categ':'CATEG_A','pagenb':2,},
{'ID':'id3','ref':'ref1','categ':'CATEG_B','pagenb':3}
```

To this:

```
{'ID':['id1','id2],'ref':'ref1','categ':'CATEG_A'},

{'ID':'id3','ref':'ref1','categ':'CATEG_B',},
```

in python I use pandas dataframe to groupby but I don't find the best way to do this in java
categ value is a variable dynamic, can change

Comment: ```{'ID':'id3','ref':'ref1','categ':'CATEG_B',}``` should be ```{'ID':['id3'],'ref':'[ref1]','categ':'CATEG_B'}```?   I would use a map where the key is a string and the value is a list of string.

Comment: why not, no problem

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
    Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
        "[" +
        "  {\"ID\":\"id1\",\"ref\":\"ref1\",\"categ\":\"CATEG_A\",\"pagenb\":1}," +
        "  {\"ID\":\"id2\",\"ref\":\"ref1\",\"categ\":\"CATEG_A\",\"pagenb\":2}," +
        "  {\"ID\":\"id3\",\"ref\":\"ref1\",\"categ\":\"CATEG_B\",\"pagenb\":3}" +
        "]");
        
    JsonNode node = josson.getNode("group(map(ref, categ), ID).map(ID, key.ref, key.categ)");
    System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ {
  "ID" : [ "id1", "id2" ],
  "ref" : "ref1",
  "categ" : "CATEG_A"
}, {
  "ID" : [ "id3" ],
  "ref" : "ref1",
  "categ" : "CATEG_B"
} ]
```